# Using PDO to perform functions with a query that is based on results of another query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, odbc

I'm currently using PDO to do a select on a MySQL table and I have it printing the results, which are correct in terminal.

I'm trying to apply a 'while' loop to it that selects records from an odbc database where the `order_id` from the first query is equal to the `invnoc` in the 2nd query. I think my issue is how I call the `order_id` and execute the statement in the DB2 portion.

If i run this:

```
$ordStatSql = 'SELECT order_id, order_status, is_placement, date_updated 
            FROM order_status';
try{
$ordStat = $MysqlConn->prepare($ordStatSql);
$result = $ordStat->execute();
}
 catch(PDOException $ex)
{
  echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
 }

while($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

{
    echo $row['order_id'] . $row['order_status'] . $row['is_placement'] . $row['date_updated'] . "\n";

}
```

It runs fine, no errors, and prints every row that I anticipate.

But the full script:

```
 $ordStatSql = 'SELECT order_id, order_status, is_placement, date_updated 
            FROM order_status';
try{
$ordStat = $MysqlConn->prepare($ordStatSql);
$result = $ordStat->execute();
}
 catch(PDOException $ex)
{
  echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
 }

while($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

{
    echo $row['order_id'] . $row['order_status'] . $row['is_placement'] . $row['date_updated'] . "\n";

    $detailStatCheck = '
        SELECT 
             invnoc as INVOICE,
             fstatc as STATUS,
             cstnoc AS DEALER,
             framec AS FRAME,
             covr1c AS COVER,
             colr1c AS COLOR ,
             extd2d AS SHIPDATE,
             orqtyc AS QUANTITY
        FROM GPORPCFL
        WHERE invnoc IN ?
        ORDER BY invnoc asc 
    ';

    try{
    $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
    $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute(['order_id']);
    $count2 = $detailCheck->rowcount();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
echo "Matches:" . $count2
```

It prints the same order_id numbers and obviously takes longer but matches shows -1. I know it's pulling matches because I run it manually and it matches every record. I'm wondering if I'm looping incorrectly or it it comes down to a PDO error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `WHERE invnoc IN ?` try `WHERE invnoc IN (?)'` or `WHERE invnoc = ?` if you don't need IN. This also looks incorrect `$detailCheck->execute(['order_id']);`, I believe it should be `$detailCheck->execute([$row['order_id']]);`

Comment: Hmm, I made those changes but I still get the Matches: -1    , no errors though; I just can't verify that it's matching

Comment: For the purposes of testing you can hard code `$detailCheck->execute(['1234']);` only if you are sure that this order id exists and it will always return some result. Were you getting any errors before and not now?

Comment: `rowCount()` doesn't reliably work for `SELECT` queries with ODBC. Try doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GPORPCFL WHERE invnoc = ? ORDER BY invnoc asc` and then `$count2 = $detailCheck->fetch()[0];`

Comment: @ishegg I applied Bamar's 2nd solution below and modified it with your count syntax and it looks like it returned the correct number. So it's working right, I just didn't have it formatted to dump properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `WHERE invnoc IN ?` should be `= ?`. `IN` is used for matching against values in a list, not a single value.

Second, you need to provide the value from the row in the call to `execute()`:

```
$detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute($row['order_id']);
```

Third, there's no point in using `ORDER BY invnoc`, since you're just matching a single `invnoc` value.

Fourth, you're overwriting the `$count2` variable each time through the loop. You should initialize it to `0` before the loop, and then increment it, so you get the total:

```
$count2 += $detailCheck->rowCount();
```

You also don't need to prepare the query each time through the loop. The query doesn't change, so you can just prepare it once before the loop, and execute it in the loop.

Another option is to collect all the `order_id` values into an array, and prepare a query that matches all of them at once with `IN`.

```
$order_ids = [];
while ($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $order_ids[] = $row['order_id'];
}
if (count($order_ids) > 0) {
    $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($order_ids), '?'));
    $detailStatCheck = "
        SELECT 
             invnoc as INVOICE,
             fstatc as STATUS,
             cstnoc AS DEALER,
             framec AS FRAME,
             covr1c AS COVER,
             colr1c AS COLOR ,
             extd2d AS SHIPDATE,
             orqtyc AS QUANTITY
        FROM GPORPCFL
        WHERE invnoc IN ($placeholders)
        ORDER BY invnoc asc 
    ";
    try {
        $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
        $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute($order_ids);
        $count2 = $detailCheck->rowCount();
        echo "Matches: $count2";
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going ahead and accepting but before I fully apply one approach or the other: Once I work through this I'm going to use the matches to perform an insert to another table. That being said, which approach do you think would be most beneficial for performing more functions like that after this step?

Comment: Minimizing the number of queries is usually preferable, so the second approach. If you're inserting into another table in DB2, you can use `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of doing the inserts as a separate query.

Comment: I'll be inserting into mysql but that still will make it more concise I believe. The DB2 is there to check the order number and then if it matches, pull the above list of info for each record and insert into mysql. I have an error with the first solution so I'm attempting the 2nd now

Comment: Ok I've applied the 2nd solution, no errors, but still returning matches: -1. Now when I replace the variable with a hard coded order ID, it shows that it's matched

Comment: I don't see how it could be `-1`. If it's not matching it should return `0`.

Comment: Right, and when I run print_r on $detail_check, it prints the query with 284 question marks in the placeholders list so I know it's pulling the origin IDs. Checking the result now

Comment: Can you see my last comment  to Ishegg above? Using fetch on the count returned the correct number of records

Comment: I had actually written a comment about `rowCount()` possibly not working with DB2, but you said it was working with a hard-coded order ID, so I didn't think that was an issue.

Comment: That's what was confusing, when I put in a hard coded ID, it said matches was equal to every record, not just 1

Comment: Still keeping your answer, and sorry for the confusion. I just wanted to verify the matches first

Comment: So now to perform an insert of the 8 columns I'm getting in my latest query, I can just build an array of those values and use them in the insert statement through PDO?

Comment: `fetch()` returns an array already, you can just use that if you use named placeholders instead of `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is working fine (other than what the other answers/comments say). Your problem is actually using `rowCount()` on a `SELECT` query on a ODBC database. From [the manual](http://php.net/odbc_num_rows):

> Using odbc_num_rows() to determine the number of rows available after a SELECT will return -1 with many drivers.

So if you need the count, you need to select `COUNT(*)` as a field and then see the value:

```
while($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['order_id'] . $row['order_status'] . $row['is_placement'] . $row['date_updated'] . "\n";

    $detailStatCheck = '
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM GPORPCFL
        WHERE invnoc = ?
    ';

    try {
        $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
        $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute(['order_id']);
        $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch()[0]; // <---- correct count
    }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: So quick question: This way, with the count, returns the correct numbers. So in order to grab the 8 columns of info I need to do a later insert I can just change it back since I confirmed the return value?

Comment: @TomN. You could just stick with your existing query and count the number of rows in your fetch loop.

Comment: @Barmar thanks that makes sense. I can use that to test my data and not have to switch back and forth. That's going to help when I build an array of that invoice data as well